# Calculus and Analytical Geometry III (infinite series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

1) Does the following series converge or diverge? Find its sum if possible.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{(1 + n + n^2)}\right)$

2) Find the sum of the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n+2^{-n}}{n}$

3)Is the following series convergent or divergent?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{n^2} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^3}$

Comment: 1) I have tried the nth term test, does not work because limit is 0.
Didn't try root/ratio test because it doesn't seem to fit. And I have no idea how to integrate this so I was left with DCT/LCT. Dividing by (1/n^2) just gives me a infinity*0                                                           2) I've tried separating the sum, which gives us (-1)^n/n + 1/n2^n and we can separate that into two sums because first one is conditionally convergent  by alternating series test and second one is convergent by   LCT. But I have no idea how to compute sums of non geometric/telescoping series.

Comment: 3) I tried the root test*2 but the result was 1 so inconclusive. Wolframalpha says it's convergent by ratio test but I can't solve the operation.

Comment: (1) pi/2 , (2) 0, (3) converges to 0.588128...

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks several unrelated questions in the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.Notice that

$\displaystyle\arctan\dfrac{1}{n^2+n+1}\sim\dfrac{1}{n^2+n+1}\sim\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

Also, we have $\displaystyle\arctan\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}=\arctan\frac1n-\arctan\frac{1}{n+1}$.

So $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\arctan\dfrac{1}{n^2+n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\arctan\frac1n-\arctan\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

**Hint** $\displaystyle\arctan x-\arctan y=\arctan\frac{x-y}{1+xy}$

**2**.Since$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{-n}}{n}$ both are convergent, we can split them.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac1i+2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2i})\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac1i+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i})\\\displaystyle=-\ln(2n)+\ln(n)\\=-\ln2$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=\int_{0}^x(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n})'\displaystyle\mathrm dx=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-x}\mathrm dx=-\ln(1-x),x\in[-1,1)$

Let $\displaystyle x=\dfrac12,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n 2^n}=\ln2$

we get$\displaystyle\sum\frac{(-1)^n+2^{-n}}{n}=0$

**3**.$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n(1-\frac1n)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n+n^2\ln(1-\dfrac1n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n+n^2(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}-o(\frac{1}{n^3}))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt e}<1$

So it is convergent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does the sign ~ mean exactly? Also, I do not understand how you found out the value of the two sums. Do you base it all on x^n/n ? If so, why?

For the 3), I understand you first used the root test then took the limit. But how did you get to 1/e^(1/2)?

Comment: @Sadem, $\sim$ means they are both convergent or divergent. Also, i edit it again.

Comment: @Lorence About the second series, I think you should justify the split.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini  I am a little confused about what you said.

Comment: @Lorence What you have done is $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}+2^{-n}}{n}=$$ $$=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2^{-n}}{n}$$ this passage isn't always possible. Why in this case works? You should justify it.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Is it OK after my edit?

Comment: Solid answers.  +1